# QGis 2.0.1 cpp-plugin for Windows

Tags: qgis-plugins, c++

my plugin, developed in VS2008 for Windows runs in my testenvironment, the startimage of QGIS shows the developermeeting in Essen with the version number 2.1 alpha.
On a other system I have installed a QGIS Version 2.0.1, the plugin dll is in the right directory (c:\osgeo4w\apps\qgis\plugins) but i can't get it, not even in the invalids.
I'm searching for a way deploying my plugin by copying in a installed 'official' version of qgis. I'm not able to make an own install-package for qgis with my plugin and also that isn't it what my boss wants :-)
Pleas give me some supprort.
Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

I just want to update my plugin to QGis 2.0 (Dufour). But I don't know how to do that. I got the actual sources from git, added my plugin-code, compiled it in Visual Studio 2010, put the plugin-dll in the right directory. But it isn't in the plugin-list. I put the plugin-dll in a QGis 2.1-plugin-directory and it works fine. What do I wrong? I spent a lot of time and it is so frustrating. Everywhere in the forum the people say , developer should update their plugins to the new API. But how to do that?

Comment: Now I installed the weekly master-build from 16th Sept. Its a version 2.1. it won't work :-(

Comment: What is the great difference between the nightly built master (there it works) and the weekly master setup? why the version numbers are 2.1 and 2.0.1?

Comment: I didn't solved the problem. But I explored the Versions of the two QGIS-Versions: QGIS Dufuor (2.0.1) is compiled against Qt 4.8.5 and GDAL 1.10 while QGIS Master(2.1) where my plugin is running only was compiled against Qt 4.7.1 and GDAL 1.9. Now my Question: How can I convert my plugin, do I need other sources of qgis to compile my plugin? Or do I have wrong cmake-scripts to create my visual-studio-project? Please give me someone a hand. I despare of it.